# Can Encryption Scope be set for an Azure Storage Account using Java API

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to encrypt Azure containers using dedicated keys from Key Vaults.
For example:

Storage Account -> Encryption Scope 1, Encryption Scope 2

Storage Account -> Container 1 (encrypted by Encryption Scope 1)

```
               Container 2 (encrypted by Encryption Scope 2)
```

The encryption scope themselves are mapped to distinct key vault keys

I would need to implement this using the Azure Java API and have a sample code as follows:

```
    BlobContainerEncryptionScope encryptionScope = new BlobContainerEncryptionScope();
    encryptionScope.setDefaultEncryptionScope("datalakeencscope");

    BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobContainerClientBuilder
            .connectionString(storageConnectString)
            .blobContainerEncryptionScope(encryptionScope)
            .containerName("data-lake-enc-container")
            .buildClient();
    blobContainerClient.create();
```

What I am unable to figure out, is how to assign the encryption scope to the storage account using the Java API. Any code snippets or API reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In above code are you getting any errors?

Comment: The above code is working fine, but what I am trying to find out is how to create the encryption scope in the first place. For example I would need to create the scope datalakeencscope, under the storage account. 
encryptionScope.setDefaultEncryptionScope("datalakeencscope");